# listen to changes in the value of an observable

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, observable

I'm trying to use ionic's loadingcontroller together with a firestore query. As far as I know, this returns an observable and also listens to changes in the value of the query.

But is there a way of knowing within the function if the value of the observable has been changed? Because now the loader shows up on every click even if nothing has changed, I'd like the loader only to show up if the result of the query changed.

This is what I'd like to do

```
category(category){
  let loading = this.load.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });



  this.selected = category;

    this.fsp.getCategory(category).subscribe(res => {
      if(res has changed){
         loading.present();
      this.data = this.group.groupEvents(res);
         loading.dismiss();
       } else(observable value remained the same) {
           this.data = this.group.groupEvents(res);
           }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure cause I haven't used firestore in a long time, but 
maybe you could get the "current" value using `valueChanges()` and store it in a prev var and each time the subscription fires, compare and act accordingly.